# BaseAdapter changes variable values

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter

Still rather new to this android/java thing. I am now using a extended `BaseAdapter` to show the content of an array. When calling the adapter I am trying to send the value of a boolean with it. When sending, the variable is first set as the value I am trying to set, but when entering the getView()-function, the value has been reset to false or 0(depending on whether I am using a bool or an int. Does anyone know what is going on?

My code is below :

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    boolean run = false; 
    public String msg;
    boolean out; 

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView listView;

    private RowAdapter radapter; 

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            radapter = new RowAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, out, arrayList);
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(radapter);

            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        }


        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                String str = et.getText().toString();
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    newOutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                        true);
                printWriter.println(str);
                out = true; 
                AddChat(str);
                radapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        class ClientThread implements Runnable {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                run = true; 
                try{
                     if(msg!=null){
                        AddChat(msg);
                        out = false; 
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(newRunnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run(){
                                                     radapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }           
                }catch(UnknownHostException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }catch(IOException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
        public void AddChat(String msg){
            arrayList.add(msg);
        }
}
```

**RowAdapter.java**

```
public RowAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, boolean out,ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
    super();

    this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
    this.out=out; 
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){ 
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)        context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(textViewResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    String s = arrayList.get(position);

    if (out) {
        if (s != null) {
        TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            TextView message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            if ((message!= null) &&(label!=null)) {
                label.setText("");
                message.setText(s);
            }
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow);
           ((RelativeLayout) convertView).setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        }
   }

    if (!out) {
        if (s != null) {
        TextView label = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            TextView message = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            if ((message!= null) &&(label!=null)) {
                label.setText("");
                message.setText(s);
            }
        }

    }
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String readableTimestamp = (String)DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp);
    TextView date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
    date.setText(readableTimestamp);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
   return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting that the `out` in `MainActivity` is somehow replicated to `RowAdapter`?

When this line is executed in `MainActivity`:

```
radapter = new RowAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, out, arrayList);
```

The `RowAdapter`'s `out` will be set to whatever value `MainActivity`'s `out` contains at the time. I'm surprised if you don't see a warning here, as `out` hasn't even been initialized there.

If you want to set the `out` member in the `RowAdapter` from `MainActivity` at a later point, you'll need to implement a setter, such as:

In RowAdapter.java:

```
private boolean out;

public void setOut( boolean value ) {
    this.out = value;
}
```

And then in `MainActivty`, change `out = true` to `radapter.setOut( true );` etc.

Answer (score 0):

> When calling the adapter I am trying to send the value of a boolean
>   with it.

I don't understand what you mean by this. What do you mean by "Calling the adapter".

> When sending, the variable is first set as the value I am trying to
>   set, but when entering the getView()-function, the value has been
>   reset to false or 0(depending on whether I am using a bool or an int.

In the `getView()` function, what value are you referring to?

If you are refering to `out` then you should know that `Java` passes Objects via reference (`ArrayList` is an object) but passes primitives by values (`boolean` is a primitive).

When you change the arrayList variable in the Activity, it will change in the `Adapter` as they are both references to the same `Object`.

When you change `out` variable in the Activity, it will only change in the Activity, as the `out` variable in your adapter is not connected to it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `out` is a primitive type, which means that when you pass it to an object, you're only passing a copy of the value but not the reference. A solution could be to create a `setOut()` method to set the `out`'s value each time you change it.